# usb partition creation

Tags: partition

When I am doing dmesg after plug in my SD card to do partition

```
[ 4611.940660] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 4611.944440]  sdb: unknown partition table
[ 4611.949411] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page present
[ 4611.949419] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 4611.949424] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 4966.868425] end_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
```

First of all I think this is because of Linux kernel it can't reading (some problem with kernel) but when I just run a command for partition details

```
sudo /dev/sdb [sdb is my device name ]
Device contains neither a valid DOS partition table, nor Sun, SGI or OSF disklabel
Building a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x9b17bdaf.
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
After that, of course, the previous content won't be recoverable.
Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 4 will be corrected by w(rite)
```

Can anybody give me a solution for this?

Comment: What does `fdisk -l /dev/sdb` show?

Comment: Is there currently any data on this SD card? If not, you could use fdisk, cfdisk, parted, etc. to partition it, then mkfs on the new partition. Or the graphical tools.

Comment: when i am doing fdisk -l /dev/sdx its giving unkown device mounted...

Comment: no, there is no data in device. just tried to format the device,i deleted all partition whatever being present into it before this and when i again going to select partition its giving this errors.....but i will try your suggestion also......